# Send and recieve an XML file from client to server using python flask

Tags: python, xml, flask, python-requests

I need to send and receive a XML file stored at a client machine to a flask server. I am able to do the same for JSON file using requests but the same is not happening with XML.

This is my server side code

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True


@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    print ("************SERVER CALLED ***********")
    req_data= request.get(silent=True)

app.run(host='192.168.37.129')
```

and this is the client code

```
getlatestfile = os.getcwd()+fileseparator+"MSF"
getlatestfile=getlatestfile+fileseparator+"*.xml"
list_of_files = glob.glob(getlatestfile)
if list_of_files:
    msfFile = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
    print ("[+] Sending latest MSF file which is..."+msfFile)
    with open(msfFile) as xml:

        response = requests.post('http://192.168.37.129:5000/', data=open(msfFile).read())
        print ('response from server:',response.text)

        #k=response.text
        #print(res1.content);
        print("[+] Received response from server...Intiating run of commands as directed by server \n")


else:
    print("No Result file present in the XML directory location/file could be corrupted.")
```

I am getting the following error on  my server and host respectively

```
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'get'
```

client

```
File "test.py", line 26, in <module>
    response = requests.post('http://192.168.37.129:5000/', data=open(msfFile).read())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 112, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 490, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(32, 'Broken pipe'))
```

ANy help will be highly appreciated

Comment: You have `request.get()`. Might you possibly have meant `requests.get()`?

Comment: Thanks. but how do I send the file now. It is still requiring an argument which I am unsure what to give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try matching your port numbers for client and server. 
Also, instead of writing

```
req_data= request.get(silent=True)
```

write

```
return jsonify(request.json)
```

and change

```
response = requests.post('http://192.168.37.129:5000/', data=open(msfFile).read())
```

to

```
response = requests.post('http://192.168.37.129:5000/', json=data)
```

Comment: I am trying to send an XML file not JSON data, will this approach work ?

Comment: Python comes with built-in XML parsers. You can convert xml to json. Please take a look at this link: https://www.journaldev.com/19392/python-xml-to-json-dict